# Spring + Vue login: timeout and error handling

Tags: java, spring, vue.js

I'm trying to build a back-end in Spring and a front-end in Vue. Same machine, separated project. I solved or disabled all cors, csrf and login issue, but this one leave me totally stoned.

Spring:
SecurityConfig.java

```
package main.java.it.coderevo.security.config;

import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("allowedOrigin")
    String allowedOriginDev;

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth
            .jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
            .usersByUsernameQuery(
                  " SELECT username, password, enabled "
                + " FROM User where username = ?"
            )
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                  " SELECT username, Role.name as 'role' "
                + " FROM User "
                +   " JOIN Role ON User.idRole = Role.id "
                + " WHERE username = ?"             
            );
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/god**").hasRole("GOD")
                .antMatchers("/admin**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "GOD")
                .antMatchers("/api**").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN", "GOD")
                .antMatchers("/login**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/public**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .logout()
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID") 
            .and()
                .cors()
            .and()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .csrf().disable().httpBasic();
    }

    // To enable CORS
    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {

        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();

        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(allowedOriginDev));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList(
                    RequestMethod.GET.name(),
                    RequestMethod.POST.name()
                ));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Content-Type", "Cache-Control"));

        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

         return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

and LoginController.java:

```
package main.java.it.coderevo.controller;

import java.security.Principal;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import main.java.it.coderevo.algo.Helper;
import main.java.it.coderevo.pojo.User;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/login*")
public class LoginController {

        @Autowired
        private Helper helper;

        @RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST}, 
                        produces = "application/json")
        String getUserInfo(Principal principal) {

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();         
            User user = helper.getLoggedUser(principal);

            json.put("logged", user != null);
            if (user == null)
                json
                    .put("msg", "error looking for user info!");
            else
                json
                    .put("username", user.getUsername())
                    .put("mail", user.getMail())
                    .put("verified", user.isVerified())
                    .put("role", user.getRole().getName());

            return json.toString();         
        }
}
```

At the other side we find a classy axios on API:

```
api.login(this.usr, this.pws)
   .then( res => this.loginPass(res))
   .catch(err => this.loginError(err));
```

resolved in library:

```
login: (usr, pws) => {

      let conf = {
        withCredentials: true
      }
      if (usr && pws)
        conf.headers = {

          'Authorization': "Basic " + btoa(usr + ":" + pws)
        }

      return server.post(SERVER_URL + "login", {}, conf)
    }
```

And then, the point: is all working; login, logout, cookies...but if I post some unauthorized credentials, server gives me a timeout error instead of reporting what's going on:

```
Error: timeout of 1000ms exceeded
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleTimeout (xhr.js?b50d:95)
```

and vue show me a bit stranger behaviour, too:
[image: vue behaviour]
As you can see from when I send axios post request to when request goes in timeout (default is 1sec but modifying that value result only in shorter or longer alert form), for some reason, that bad-ugly-old-school-alert-form appear, and I can't rest in pace.

As someone at least some direction where I can start to dig? I'm actually really confused.

## UPDATE1

Main issue seems located in axios call, particularly with `withCredentials: true`. The main reason I used that option is to handle session cookie out-of-the-box. Disabling that option result in normal login behaviour (but w/o session management), enabling it give me insopportable ugly-form I can't put my hands on.

Answer (score 0):

In the last instance, that's the point: axios post a request to API w/ wrong username and/or password. Server replay with 401 with `XXX-Authenticate` header setted to `Authentication: Basic realm`.

Google Chrome arbitrarily decides to handle this situation with a prompt until axios timeout.

So the easier solution is to modify at least one of that 2 information the server replay with: you can sand a different status code (for example 400 or 403), but the best way is to leave 401 code (meaning of 401 is `unauthorized request`) and avoid authentication part in `XXX-Authentication` header.

This is a simple authentication entry point attached to my `httpBasic()` in spring that seems to resolve issue:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                [...]
                .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(new BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint() {

                    { setRealmName("codrev"); }

                    @Override
                    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {

                        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());

                        response.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", getRealmName());
                        response.setHeader("Accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*");
                        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
                        response.setHeader("cache-control", "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate");

                        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                        data.put("logged", false);

                        response.getOutputStream().println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(data));
                    }

                })
        ;
    }
```

!! `super.commence(request, response, authException)` call results in useless ignored response modification, so avoid it !!